# Wordpress core files - PHP Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: fatal-error

Our live site went down this afternoon with the open_basedir issue.  The odd thing being that it doesn't relate to media uploads etc. but to one of the core files.  The wp-admin/setup-config.php file more specifically.

Here is the full error I'm getting:

> "PHP message: PHP Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
> File(/www/{mydomain}/wp-config-sample.php) is not within the allowed path(s):
> /www/{mydomain}/public:/www/{mydomain}/mysqleditor:/www/{mydomain}/web:/www/{mydomain}/deploy:/www/{mydomain}/deployment:/www/{mydomain}/deployments:/usr/share:/tmp) in /www/{mydomain}/public/wp-admin/setup-config.php on line 46" while reading response header from upstream

Would greatly appreciate any help as this is detrimental to our business and we would be forced to start giving refunds if not resolved soon.

Comment: You'll probably have to talk to your hosting support / server admin people. This appears to be a PHP issue, not a WordPress one.

Comment: Perhaps check if any changes made to your .htaccess file. Or similar directives added by your hosting place to limit things. Do a googles/bings/ducks of 'open_basedir restriction in effect'.